# Absolute Value Definition (for a defined function $f$)?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In a document that I've seen, it says that if $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$, then

$$|f(x)| = \begin{cases}
f(x), & x \geq 0 \\
-f(x), & x < 0\text{.}
\end{cases}$$

This is consistent with the definition of $|x|$ that I've seen, so I had no reason to believe this definition was wrong. But there's one thing that confuses me: if $f(x) = x^2$,

$$|x^{2}| = \begin{cases}
x^{2}, & x \geq 0 \\
-x^{2}, & x < 0\text{.}
\end{cases}$$
There's a problem here: if $x < 0$, $-x^2$ is clearly negative. Thus, there's something wrong with the definition of $|f(x)|$ I have above since $|f(x)| \geq 0$ for all $x$ (or at least, it **should** be that way).

What is it?

Comment: It should be $$\lvert f(x)\rvert =\begin{cases} f(x) &, f(x) \geqslant 0\\ -f(x) &, f(x) < 0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Wow, that was simple - surprised I didn't catch that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer points out, you have the wrong definition. In view of this, your second function is properly written

$$
|x^2| = \begin{cases} x^2, \quad x^2 \geq 0 \\ -x^2, \quad x^2 < 0 \end{cases}
$$

and the second condition never applies.